# php: show html if a field in database is NOT empty

Tags: php, database, if-statement

I know this question in some form has been asked before, but somehow it still goes wrong in my case...

I want to show some HTML if a certain database field is NOT empty. So after following numerous options I got the following code:

```
<?
if ($remark!=="") 
{ 
    echo "<tr class=\"warning\"><td colspan=\"5\">REMARK: $item->remark </td></tr>";
} 
?>
```

But the code is generated in every case, also if the field is empty. Also, I got the following message:
Notice: Undefined variable: remark in...

If the field is empty, nothing needs to happen.

Comment: You need to show the origin/assignment of `$remark`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used undefined variable in condition.

```
if ($item->remark !== "")
```

Comment: This was the correct solution for me. (I hope this won't be deleted, as I think it is very usefull for the community to know whether an answer was correct or solved the problem.)